# install .apk file programmatically

Tags: android

I want to install the apk file programmatically in my application 
for that i write the code as follows

```
        f=new File("l.o.p-1.apk");
        Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(i);
```

but it doesn't worked and a alert dialog was displayed with the message 
             parse error :problem parsing the package
          why i get this error

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload the same APK from google site and check it will work or not, if it shows the same error that means something wrong in your apk

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install it using the command and check if you get errors:

```
adb install [your.apk]
```

Also check the location of the apk file if is valid. (I think it should be on the sdcard of the phone.. I am not sure though..)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check the location you are installing from.

e.g When I downloaded an apk to my [Cache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) folder, I got a parse error when installing but downloading it to my [External Cache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29) folder allowed the installation to proceed normally.